# I want to copy over another field but remove data in SFMC SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, developer, sfmc-business-unit, sqlserver

I have two columns, one titled "Account_Number" and the other titled "Customer_Number". There are the same, except Customer_Number has "C" in front of it. If I have all the Customer_Number values filled in, is it possible in SQL in Salesforce Marketing Cloud to grab all those values and remove the 'C' and then put them in the "Account_Number" column? E.g. C12345 --> 12345 (Account_Number).

I looked at the REPLACE functions but don't believe Marketing Cloud supports anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although limited in scope, the SQL version in Marketing Cloud does support the Replace function. You could even use Substring if you would feel fancy, but this will do the job:

```
Select
    Replace(Customer_Number, 'C', '') as Account_Number,
From
    Your_Data_Extension
```